# How is $\,(e^{\pi})^{{{\left(e^{\pi/2}\right)}^{\left(e^{\pi/2}\right)}}^{\ldots\infty}}=-1\,?$

Tags: complex-numbers

So, here's how I've arrived to that conclusion.

My first question was: can $\,e^{i\pi}\,$ be written as $\,(e^\pi)^i\,?$

Well, by taking $\,\log_e$ to both sides of the equation $\,{e^{i\pi}}=-1\,,\,$ we get $\,\log_e{i}=i\pi/2\,$ which is true. And similarly doing it for the other equation $({e^\pi})^i = -1\,,\,$ it holds true.
So they are equivalent forms.

And again $\,(e^\pi)^i=(e^\pi)^{e^{{i\pi}/2}}=-1\,.$

Now if we repeatedly replace $i$ with $e^{i\pi/2}$, we obtain

$\,(e^{\pi})^{{{\left(e^{\pi/2}\right)}^{\left(e^{\pi/2}\right)}}^{\ldots\infty}}=-1\,.$

Is this just true or have I done something wrong here?

Comment: In this case, I think this happens to work though in general you have to be careful with exponentials of complex numbers. 

However, you can’t just take the limit to infinity since a small change in the topmost exponent is a big change to the value of the expression, so it doesn’t converge in the normal limit sense.

Comment: When talking about a tower of exponents, it is necessary to say (in words or in notation) in what order they are being exponentiated. Is it from the top down? From the bottom up? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of depends on exactly what you mean. When you ask if $(e^\pi)^{(e^{\pi/2})^\cdots}=-1$, I interpret it as you asking if
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (e^\pi)^{(e^{\pi/2})^{\text{...($n$ iterations)...}^{(e^{\pi/2})}}}=-1.
\end{align*}
Every term in this sequence is a positive real number, so clearly this cannot hold. However, if we toss that $i$ up at the top, then sure, every term equals $-1$, so we are ultimately dealing with a constant sequence and of course it converges to $-1$. My point is that if one sees the expression $(e^\pi)^{(e^{\pi/2})^\cdots}$ in a vacuum, your notation would not suggest there's an $i$ hidden in the question.

Comment: the upper most exponential term has an $i$ in it that you missed.

Comment: I did not miss that. Here, I'll make an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables, then $$f(x,f(x,f(x,\dots)))\tag1$$ is not really well-defined.

The best we can do is define a sequence, by choosing $y_0,$ and then defining $y_{n+1}=f(x,y_n)$ and get a limit. But the limit depends on $y_0.$ So it is an abuse of notation to write the limit as $(1),$ which doesn't not appear to depend on another value.

If every $y_0$ gives the same limit, then $(1)$ can be justified.

What you've shown is that **if** there is one limit for all complex $y_0,$ then the limit of this expression is $-1.$ But that just means there isn't one limit.

---

It might even be clearer if we define $g(y)=f(x,y)$ for fixed $x.$ Then you'd write:

$$g(g(g(g(\cdots))))$$ which clearly means nothing. The limit of the sequence will sometimes exist and be independent of the the starting value - say, when $g$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) - but those cases are very rare.

---

If $g(y)=-y,$ the only starting value which converges is $y_0=0.$ But would we really say:

$$-(-(-(\dots)))=0?$$ It seems strange to write that, even though any $y_0$ gives a sequences whose [Cesàro mean](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean) converges to $0.$